# Want to Create A Combination of Non-Decreasing Elements with Condition

Tags: matlab, combinations

I want to create a combination of non-decreasing elements. The combination will be like,

If i=10 and w=5, then the elements of the combination can be any value from 1 to w and the sum will be equal to i.

Possible combinations are like,

1+1+1+1+1+5

1+1+1+1+1+1+4

1+1+1+1+1+1+1+3

1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
......

But 1+1+1+7 is not a desired combination because 7 is greater than w

How to get the combinations using MatLab? I need to get the combinations for higher values of i and w like may be i=20 and w=8.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive function. The following code contains a wrapper function and the recursive function which does the actual work:

```
function result = partitions(s,M)
%// s: desired sum; M: maximum value
result = partitions_rec(s,1,M,s);
end

function mat = partitions_rec(s,m,M,n)
%// s: desired sum, m: minimum value; M: maximum value; n: number of entries
M = min(M,s);
if s==0
    mat = zeros(1,n);
else
    mat = [];
    for ii = m:M;
        aux = partitions_rec(s-ii,ii,M,n-1);
        if size(aux,1)
            mat = [ mat; ii*ones(size(aux,1),1) aux ];
        end
    end
end
end
```

Example:

```
>> result = partitions(5,3)
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     2     0
     1     1     3     0     0
     1     2     2     0     0
     2     3     0     0     0
```

A 0 indicates no number. If you want to remove the zeros, you need to put the result in the form of a cell array, where each cell is a vector with nonzero values:

```
result_cell = arrayfun(@(ii) result(ii, logical(result(ii,:))), 1:size(result,1), 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

In the example, this would give

```
>> result_cell{:}
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1
ans =
     1     1     1     2
ans =
     1     1     3
ans =
     1     2     2
ans =
     2     3
```

Comment: Hi, i do not know how to run this code. I have two parameters and I want to put only the values of i and w and want to get the output. Would you please let me know what are the input parameters in your code and how can i get the output?

Comment: @user3136967 Copy all the code (the two functions), paste it on a file and save it as "partitions.m". Place that file in Matlab's path (for example in your user folder). Then type at command prompt `partitions(20,8)` or whatever input values you need.

Comment: @LuisMendo the code just worked fine for me. Thank You very much!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you again for your previous solution. Now if i want to control the number of entries then what I will have to do? Suppose, I want to keep the number of entries always 5 then how can I do it? Please suggest.

Comment: @user3136967 Do you mean the number of rows of `result`? My function will give you all of them. You could randomly select 5 of them using `result = result(randperm(size(result,1)),:); result = result(1:5,:)`

Comment: @LuisMendo I am talking about the columns. I always want to keep the number of columns = 5, like the total sum of a row will be more than 5 but it cannot exceed 5 entries example: 1+1+1+1+5